# How can I get a message to appear when I submit a form using Happy.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I tried to include a conditional in the unHappy function; While the form processes, I don't get the message indicating success! Here's my code.

```
var dd= $.noConflict();

  dd(document).ready(function () {
    dd('.success').hide();
        dd('#frmContact').isHappy({
            fields: {
              // reference the field you're talking about, probably by `id`
              // but you could certainly do $('[name=name]') as well.
              '#yourName': {
                required: true,
                message: 'Might we inquire your name'
              },
              '#email': {
                required: true,
                message: 'How are we to reach you sans email??',
                test: happy.email // this can be *any* function that returns true or false
              },
              '#comments': {
                required: true,
                message: 'Please leave a message!',
              }
          },
          unHappy: function () {
            var yourName = dd('#yourName').val();
            var email = dd('#email').val();
            var comments = dd('#comments').val();
                if (yourName && email && comments == true){
                    dd('.success').show();
                            return;

            } 
        },
      });
  });
```

Comment: looking at plugin source, it does not seem to support any ajax submittal, so will submit using browser default process. No way with javascript to display messages when that occurs...will load server script redirect page

Comment: Thanks, for responding. I suppose I'll have to write the function outside the scope of isHappy, but wouldn't that path result in me revalidating everything separately, which would defeat the purpose of using isHappy?

Comment: likely best to just switch validation plugins to one that has more robust API

Comment: Good idea. Thanks Charlie! 
For anyone else out there running into this problem. Check out http://parsleyjs.org/ Looks like it has a lot of documentation!